# Syntax error creating ViewModel with KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I am creating a SPA and want to implement KnockoutJS. I am using framework4.
When I try to create a ViewModel I get a syntax error saying **Expected identifier or string**

```
var vm = {
    BankmedStatements: ko.observableArray(),
};
```

Ajax Call:

```
 function GetStatements(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/LoadBankmedStatements",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Hi");
                vm.BankmedStatements(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d)));
            },

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    };
```

Codebehind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<BankmedStatements> LoadBankmedStatements()
    {
        List<BankmedStatements> statements = new List<BankmedStatements>();
        Live_DailyEntities db = new Live_DailyEntities();

        foreach (var item in db.BankmedStatments.Where(u=>u.fFileName == "ppn_recon_20131011.csv"))
        {

        }

        return statements;

    }
```

I am not sure if I forgot to reference some library but here is my references:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What browser? IE doesn't like commas at on the last property of an object

Comment: Using Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Is that all your code? i mean maybe the error in some where else

Comment: try to put breakpoint and debug your JavaScript objects

Comment: @ebramtharwat it hits my function but then I get an Internal Server Error. Browser shows that error message mentioned above

Comment: @G-Man you are not returning JSON!!!

Comment: You are referencing knockout and knockout mapping both twice in your references... Only reference the debug ones while you are debugging.

Also you are referencing jquery twice...

Comment: @ebramtharwat I am returning json! Although my object is empty it still return my empty object as json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix your references by eliminating duplicates.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Are you using WebAPI? It looks like you are so those objects are getting turned into JSON which is good. However, in your success function

```
vm.BankmedStatements(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d)));
```

What is "response.d". More then likely your response is an array of JSON objects so response.d is an invalid reference.

Comment: No I am not using WebApi, I am just doing a call to my code behind. response.d will contain my data that is being returned in json format.